# Ext JS - Bind multiple formfields to one field of the model

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a model with a hex color field. The user can edit it as rgb via 3 separate numberfields. I'm trying to bind the field to these components but I'm not sure how to do it. I tried putting them in a container and binding the container to the field. However my setValue isn't called when a numberfield is changed.

I guess I could add listeners to the numberfields but I was hoping there was a better way to go about it.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23t2

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes. It will work for both scenario,

1. if user change from color name(`textfield`) then RGB will change.
2. If user will change from number field than color name(`textfield`) will be changed.

Try this code in your sencha [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23t2)

```
Ext.create({
    xtype: 'viewport',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    viewModel: {
        data: {
            theColor: {
                name: 'Blue',
                hex: '3366CC'
            }
        },
        formulas: {
            containerValue: {
                bind: '{theColor.hex}',
                get: function (value) {
                    return {
                        hex: value
                    };
                },
                set: function (value) {
                    this.set('theColor.hex', value.hex);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    items: [{
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'form',
        bodyPadding: 10,
        height: 300,

        fieldDefaults: {
            labelWidth: 90,
        },

        items: [{
            xtype: 'component',
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
            bind: {
                style: {
                    background: '#{theColor.hex}'
                }
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            bind: '{theColor.name}',
            listeners:{
                blur:function(textfield,e,eOpts){
                    var viewModel = textfield.up('viewport').getViewModel();
                        colorName = textfield.getValue(),
                        hex = colorToHex(colorName);
                    viewModel.set('theColor',{
                     name: colorName,
                     hex: hex
                    });
                    function colorToRGBA(color) {
                        // Returns the color as an array of [r, g, b, a] -- all range from 0 - 255
                        // color must be a valid canvas fillStyle. This will cover most anything
                        // you'd want to use.
                        // Examples:
                        // colorToRGBA('red')  # [255, 0, 0, 255]
                        // colorToRGBA('#f00') # [255, 0, 0, 255]
                        var cvs, ctx;
                        cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
                        cvs.height = 1;
                        cvs.width = 1;
                        ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
                        ctx.fillStyle = color;
                        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
                        return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
                    }

                    function byteToHex(num) {
                        // Turns a number (0-255) into a 2-character hex number (00-ff)
                        return ('0'+num.toString(16)).slice(-2);
                    }

                    function colorToHex(color) {
                        // Convert any CSS color to a hex representation
                        // Examples:
                        // colorToHex('red')            # '#ff0000'
                        // colorToHex('rgb(255, 0, 0)') # '#ff0000'
                        var rgba, hex;
                        rgba = colorToRGBA(color);
                        hex = [0,1,2].map(
                            function(idx) { return byteToHex(rgba[idx]); }
                            ).join('');
                        return hex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'container',

            setValue: function (value) {
                const hex = value.hex || '000000';

                const red = parseInt(hex.substr(0, 2), 16);
                const green = parseInt(hex.substr(2, 2), 16);
                const blue = parseInt(hex.substr(4, 2), 16);

                const items = this.query('');

                items[0].setValue(red);
                items[1].setValue(green);
                items[2].setValue(blue);
            },

            bind: {
                value: '{containerValue}',
            },

            defaults: {
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                maxValue: 255,
                minValue: 0,
                allowBlank: false,
                width: 175,
                listeners:{
                    change:function(numberfield){
                        if(numberfield.hasFocus){
                            var viewModel = numberfield.up('viewport').getViewModel(),
                                items = this.up().query(''),
                                red =  items[0].getValue() || 0,
                                green = items[1].getValue() || 0,
                                blue = items[2].getValue() || 0,
                                hex = rgbToHex(red,green,blue);
                            viewModel.set('theColor',{
                             name: hex,//For hex to color name you have to search for that, here I am giving hax color.
                             hex: hex
                            });
                            function componentToHex(c) {
                                var hex = c.toString(16);
                                return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
                            }

                            function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
                                return componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'R',
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'G',
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'B',
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setValue` is only called on a form field. Form fields are denoted by the config `isFormField: true`. Note however that `setValue` is not the only function expected on a form field; there are dozens others (e.g. `getValue`, `getModelValue`, `isValid`, ...).

Because of this, I always use a `hiddenfield` to aggregate other form fields, not a `container`, and then I use change listeners to keep hiddenfield and other fields synchronized (bind should work as well, but our app is still MVC). I also annotate the other fields with

```
excludeForm: true,
submitValue: false,
```

to make sure that the values are not submitted and do not affect the "dirty" state of the form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I switched to a ´hiddenfield´ but I'm really not sure how to bind the numberfields to it. Could you show an example?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23t4